# How to select rows based on a certain criteria from subsets in a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a test table with an ActionId column. The column contains an increasing and random number of rows with values of 1 to 5 and then it starts again with another subset of values from 1 to 5. The data can have one or more subsets like that.

I am interested in rows which contain ActionId of values 4 or 5 but only the last one in each subset. So in this sample, **I want to return rows 7 and 11**. Row id 7 because 5 is the last value before the value goes down and row id 11 because 4 is the last value before the value goes down again. For the last subset, the value doesn't need to go down again. The value 4 or 5 could be in the last row.

I can program this in a procedural language but I can't think of set based SQL solution.

```
 CREATE TABLE test (
    id  [int] IDENTITY(1,1)
    ,ActionId INT)

    INSERT INTO [test] (ActionId ) VALUES
    (1), (2), (3), (3), (4), (4), (5), (3), (3), (3), (4), (1),(2)

select * from test
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4ffe71/3

Comment: In SQL Server 2008, you could use an apply or a subquery (e.g. `outer apply (select top 1 t2.actionid from test as t2 where t2.id > test.id order by t2.id) as c where (c.actionid < test.actionid or c.ActionId is null) and test.actionid in (4, 5)`). In a newer version of SQL Server, you might use `LEAD()` to achieve a similar result.

Comment: You need all values where the next row's value is less that the current value, right? What output you are expecting? 5 and 4 in two different row in a column?

Answer (score 1):

The solution I came up with involves a simple correlated subquery and a common table expression:

```
;with cte as
(
select  id, 
        ActionId,
        isnull((
            select top 1 ActionId
            from test as t1
            where t0.id < t1.id
            order by t1.id 
        ), 0) as nextActionId
from test As t0
)

select id, ActionId
from cte
where actionId IN(4,5)
and actionId > nextActionId
```

The subquery gets the next actionId for each row, based on the order of the `id` column.  The `isnull` is there for the last row - to return `0` instead of `null`.

Then, all you have to do is query the cte where the actionId is either 4 or 5 and it is larger than the next action id.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess correct, You need all values where the next row's value is less that the current value. If I am correct, You can use self join for your purpose. The following script will give you the desired output-

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
    id  [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    Actionid INT
)

INSERT INTO @test (Actionid ) 
VALUES
(1), (2), (3), (3), (4), (4), (5), (3), (3), (3), (4), (1),(2)

SELECT A.*
FROM @test A LEFT JOIN @test B ON A.id = B.id-1
WHERE B.Actionid < A.Actionid
```

The output is-

```
id  Actionid
7   5
11  4
```

If you also need the last row's value without considering any condition, just change the script with below. This will include the last value 2 in the output.

```
SELECT A.*
FROM @test A LEFT JOIN @test B ON A.id = B.id-1
WHERE B.Actionid < A.Actionid 
OR B.Actionid IS NULL
```

Comment: This result is coincidence... Try to change the set by changing the `,(4),(4)` to `,(2),(2)`. You might change your WHERE to `WHERE A.Actionid IN(4,5) AND B.Actionid < A.Actionid` though... Furthermore, this would miss a 4 or a 5 in the very last row. And: Following my understanding the row 5 should show up too, as it is a 4 and it is the last entry in the second sub-set. The OP must clearify this...

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE can help you here:

--Your *mockup table*

```
DECLARE @test TABLE 
(
    id  [int] IDENTITY(1,1),
    Actionid INT
)

INSERT INTO @test (Actionid ) 
VALUES  (1), (2), (3), (3), (4), (4), (5), (3), (3), (3), (4), (1),(2);
```

--the query

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT id
          ,Actionid
          ,1 AS GroupKey
          ,1 AS GroupStep 
    FROM @test t WHERE id=1 --the IDENTITY is the sorting key obviously and will start with a 1 in this test case.

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.id
          ,t.Actionid
          ,CASE WHEN t.Actionid<=r.Actionid THEN r.GroupKey+1 ELSE r.GroupKey END
          ,CASE WHEN t.Actionid<=r.Actionid THEN 1 ELSE r.GroupStep+1 END
    FROM @test t
    INNER JOIN recCTE r ON t.id=r.id+1
)
SELECT * 
FROM recCTE;
```

The idea in short:

We start with the first row and iterate through the set *row-by-row*. Each row we test, if the `ActionId` is not increasing and set corresponding values to the `GroupKey` and the `GroupStep`.

The result

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | Actionid | GroupKey | GroupStep |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1        | 1        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 2  | 2        | 1        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 3  | 3        | 1        | 3         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 4  | 3        | 2        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 5  | 4        | 2        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 6  | 4        | 3        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 7  | 5        | 3        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 8  | 3        | 4        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 9  | 3        | 5        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 10 | 3        | 6        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 11 | 4        | 6        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 12 | 1        | 7        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 13 | 2        | 7        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

### Solving your issue

We can proceed from there by changing the final SELECT to this

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * 
FROM recCTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupKey ORDER BY GroupStep DESC);
```

The result shows the last entry per sub-set

```
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| id | Actionid | GroupKey | GroupStep |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 3  | 3        | 1        | 3         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 5  | 4        | 2        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 8  | 3        | 4        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 9  | 3        | 5        | 1         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 11 | 4        | 6        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 7  | 5        | 3        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
| 13 | 2        | 7        | 2         |
+----+----------+----------+-----------+
```

You can filter to the sub-sets where the last entry is a 4 or a 5. In this case I see the rows 7 and 11 but also the row 5. Might be I did not get the logic correctly...

Comment: How did you figure out rows 7 & 11 from the last query? I don't see anything unique about them. Can you write a query that produces those two rows only?

Comment: @Tony_Henrich Just those with `ActionId` values of 4 and 5? Did I get something wrong? What about row 5?

Answer (score 0):

This is the query I came up with:

```
WITH cte
AS
(SELECT id, Actionid, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) rn FROM test)

SELECT
    prev.id
   ,prev.Actionid prevActionId
   ,cur.Actionid curActionId
FROM cte cur
JOIN cte prev
    ON prev.rn = cur.rn - 1
WHERE
    prev.Actionid > cur.Actionid
    AND prev.Actionid IN (4, 5)
```